# What is role of Lord Hanuman in Mahabaratha?

Tags: hanuman, kurukshetra

Could someone know about Lord Hanuman helped/role in the Kurukshetra. And who requested himself to resides in the Arjuna's chariot flag either Beema or Lord Krishna.